# How to add duplicate rows using sql sum function

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

Few days ago, I came to a problem where I have to sum the value of some duplicate row in MySql & I've tried some queries but they didn't work.

Here is table data :-

```
card_id     tic_id  game_id     card_symbol     card_symbol_no  qty
1           6           1           C                   6        2
2           6           1           H                   7        6
3           6           1           C                   6        7
```

And My desired output is :-

```
card_id     tic_id  game_id     card_symbol     card_symbol_no  qty
1              6        1           C               6           (9)
2              6        1           H               7           (6)
```

some other given factor :-
1.) the "tic_id", & "game_id" is same.

Comment: Sample data for testing: http://www.sqlize.com/m77y4DSoXW

Comment: What all factors are you grouping by?  It's not clear from your example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select 
  min(card_id) as card_id, 
  tic_id, 
  game_id, 
  card_symbol, 
  card_symbol_no, 
  sum(qty) as qty
from 
  yourTabel
group by 
  tic_id, 
  game_id, 
  card_symbol, 
  card_symbol_no
```

Comment: I first overlooked the card_id. Used `min` for this now, so it returns the first card_id of the set.